# Why SSH server on windows7 x86 failed, while SSH client working

Tags: hadoop, ssh, windows-7, cygwin, sshd

I am working recently on building Hadoop environment on windows7 OS. However, I got stuck in SSH configuration which blocks all the remaining work for Hadoop. I believe it's nothing to do with Hadoop, so any one familiar with SSH can do me a great favor.

Here's the thing, I'm trying to install SSH service for two computers so that any one can communicate with the other. I have successfully installed SSH for my PC, which is win7-x64, through cygwin. However, when I repeated it on the other computer, which is a server with win7-x86, SSH server failed, while the client can work, I get totally confused.

For my PC, I installed cygwin to use SSH service. `ssh localhost` works fine. And after generating ssh keys and appending it to `authorized_keys`, I managed to log in to my PC without password.

I copied the cygwin folder from my PC to the server, which is not connected to the Internet thus cygwin can't be directly installed on it.  `ssh localhost` turned out okay at the first. But when I attemptted to log in without password by generating ssh keys and appending to `authorized_keys`, I got

```
Connection to localhost closed by remote host
Connection to localhost closed.
```

What's more, I copied the public key of the server to my PC and appended to `authorized_keys` file. I managed to log in to PC from the server without password.

On the other hand, the SSH connection from PC to server failed no matter whether with or without password. I got the same failure:

```
Connection closed by 192.168.0.52
```

where `192.168.0.52` is the ip address of the server.

What makes me more confused is when I connected to server from PC using `putty` rather than `ssh` command, I could log in to the server, with password.

In conclusion, I hope it would make the question more clearer with this graph:
[ssh connection graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7JCQ.png)

I hope any one can help me to figure out what's wrong and how to fix it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: check with `ssh -v user@host` to see any difference in authorization

Comment: I found what's happening. Thanks anyway! @matzeri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying for several centries, I finally found what's happening. When I built sshd service on the server, I didn't create a privileged account('cyg_server' by default), which I did on my PC but I forgot. Instead, I used current account for logging. Yet, the account , even the administrator, on windows doesn't have all the authorities as root on Linux does. Considering that, Cygwin considerately creates a privileged account named 'cyg_server',  we just leave it and log in using current account. Everything is okay!

Again, f**k windows(So why would I have to do that on windows. Well, if I could, I would)